# Implement constant-latency branchless multiplication efficiently

Tags: code-challenge, optimization, assembly

Modern hardware can perform multiplication very fast in a constant latency of 3~4 cycles. But some tiny chips for embedded environments sometimes lack hardware multiplication, which has to be emulated by a series of instructions.

#### Goal

You are given a primitive CPU with a set of basic operations. Your job is to implement unsigned multiplication of two 8-bit numbers, each in register `c` and `d`, after which the result will be stored in registers `a` and `b`, `a` storing the lower bits and `b` storing the higher bits. You don't have to preserve the input in `c` and `d`.

#### Spec

The machine has 26 8-bit registers from `a` to `z`, whose initial value is `0`. You are allowed to use all of them freely to implement this operation.

There are no "jumps" or branching instructions, but there are flags conditionally set according to the last operation.

- ZF : zero flag; set if the result is zero
- CF : carry flag; set if the result is "wrapped" for addition/subtraction; set if a bit was "carried out" for shift/rotation

There is no memory access.

#### Score

The total sum of latency cycles plus the number of registers used will be your score, the lower the better.

#### Available Instructions

`instr r0 r1/imm (2)` means `instr` takes two register operands, of which the second one can be an 8-bit immediate operand, and this instruction takes 2 cycles to complete.

All operations except `mov`, `swp`, `setX`, and `mskX` sets the zero flag accordingly.

- `mov r0 r1/imm (1)` : `r0 = r1`
- `swp r0 r1 (2)` : `r0 = r1`, `r1 = r0`
- `sswp r0 (2)` : swap the low 4 bits and the high 4 bits
- `setz/setnz/setc/setnc r0 (1)` : set `r0` to `1` if the specified flag was set, and `0` otherwise ; `z -> ZF, nz -> not ZF, c -> CF, nc -> not CF`
- `mskz/msknz/mskc/msknc r0 (1)` : set `r0` to `0xff` if the specified flag was set, and `0` otherwise
- `add r0 r1/imm (2)` : `r0 = r0 + r1`; CF affected
- `sub r0 r1/imm (2)` : `r0 = r0 - r1`; CF affected
- `adc r0 r1/imm (3)` : `r0 = r0 + r1 + CF`; CF affected
- `sbb r0 r1/imm (3)` : `r0 = r0 - r1 - CF`; CF affected
- `and r0 r1/imm (2)` : `r0 = r0 & r1`
- `or r0 r1/imm (2)` : `r0 = r0 | r1`
- `xor r0 r1/imm (2)` : `r0 = r0 ^ r1`
- `shr r0 (1)` : bitshift right once shifting in a zero; CF is the old least significant bit (LSB)
- `shl r0 (1)` : bitshift left once shifting in a zero; CF is the old most significant bit (MSB)
- `ror r0 (1)` : rotate right; bitshift right once shifting in the LSB; CF is the old LSB
- `rol r0 (1)` : rotate left; bitshift left once shifting in the MSB; CF is the old MSB
- `rcr r0 (2)` : rotate right with carry; bitshift right once shifting in the CF; the new CF is the old LSB
- `rcl r0 (2)` : rotate left with carry; bitshift left once shifting in the CF; the new CF is the old MSB
- `not r0 (2)` : bitwise not
- `neg r0 (2)` : two's complement negation; same as `not r0; add r0 1`; `CF = not ZF`

---

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/faP5ajor3), you can test your code that is translated to x86 assembly. Write your code below the label `mulb:`. I also added a working implementation ported from the work of @l4m2.

The tester has some limitations, though. It only supports 15 registers from `a` to `o`, and you have to write `shr a, 1` instead of `shr a` etc. because of NASM syntax.

[This is a scoring program written by @tsh.](https://tio.run/##rVhtc9s2DP6eX4F2vUhqHPml29qzY/d2WXrXu63trduXuu4iS4yjViZ1FFU7Tby/ngGkaEmO3dhuvvjEFzx4AIIA6M/B1yALZZyqYy4idhsKninIRC5DBn14r2TMJ74MZue3PXiXBDh7hYsQ4ma4ZJLdnvtZEofMbXu9gwMjrhf7BYqvxB9ixuRpkDHX87M0iZXb/Cg/8psh/Y6anj8NUtdNYs4aEPOIzT3oD8C9PgDg@bRr5uAI2g2cUWyuuqA300h8YTwzY1@ylBi6zeFPvZH/tNkAxyFwFV6ixtlRc@I1Dhae51/EiWJSayRNWtggVY2YTgMeZWgIEZmKr124hvAqTFgXmYBkky4omRPnKZJ0UQxnW3qoDcDdgg9la4QQONeDBSyIczZLK1CdAqqUl@1CfFjINwxQe0RIw@K7YdFHJfAdZC44K6HvsHJd@30IrXnrwoOTE/jZg5uVlQsUHQxwpUfC/odXKLtE6fehVVJg6lvdT/dQKPBeQhu6dRy@G9CjzUjhzoxO1zMKd2e0BmmafdnTR3gSF6tQe7tpHdienlrLa19n3QELomjNfbn/6uElVtO0EqpH5hoWmvp6daD19SpMaPawnP1utOfjh2F2vIbZCSnai1YQVX3/7Acdhr@G14N6bjx@GIrac/i7luIPuJDvF3MmZfbL4/yODiH3V3GznYr5j@j4tJ2O7FJud9PNuVQKC9a5QfWEBoNBH9pbKEz2VNiav2it6KysY@1DRlsGiBQPZXVlER1Ay/Xy29ZV@bm3BaWH9cuKY1abghemKXjube@zUG7XnlRvef1W7@pHgnmpyVJJ2cKHYfKAFLf1q2Gpu4TtvcmF2qnZ@6/W0W2BT6liG3xjtgV5ZEBKvcc76V0sG3Ds5oVUZxJvGnltyrIsmGDeom7dKEeStFUkzGe0zT0f6pb@ybXu6PHtsBjZAT0bFufY3q/KFLh6JZUixKHP5vhGoQeNYRMx/0LIswCfEfbJQLrjC9BjP2F8oi7xnJ95Vdbu47@FAHxEXEEgJ/mUcZX5jwsDLBFVPGHQxMozpFwdkvoGiLRNPx1dxpZbiMGjt@PPLFQ@cldCXaXMvwyytzP@ToqUSXXlh0GSuPY109CPM2@F5z/8CxczDiQRqFhwvWsN1wJGn50B1PxGloyhZh1yAh24uYH6JB12Bw4PqePTED7F1QqhN0IB4yKfXG5wnba8@WkYHH8bPWni6WbKRR@tGvYqlsham4Wss0uRJxGMGZZ3qoRxhq/AGmzxjJzQcQwRb4Nh2gZPB0Ehw@YszBUzQU0BUjXOXBmiR3ALYEnGNqA@s6jaQAuCjGoe07Xa7IOdIg61L9HveK/jlaCrjjDB1ytWSbzKjZhTU1HK3@cWtGDpFfOSJXzPKih8tC0acqigkSVLoIMKXM2nm334niFWtEPU3OFrLgs1pn14k0/HTLpVUsSDFilV6g@TGVeD9zX/GiRxRDgsigM0vKC0onw3X5PdZSgsbNDrNF/eazPGBFj@IYJp5K/Ceh0Vvu9zNoP3TLn07QTjMHIagJ8mYyaB@jNI63@yUER5I2/kZ2imi9gGOsqn6anglKOLAtqwRDZkekszDaIzHrntttcAp@fgW4W4VKnqP5d0kA7o9HCH03XMm2aI4xEJnr6yU1jLcPwBx0emTI38zyLmrtNwPFMPiuKUU4KdyICO2MVzQs/iL1bJOPudjfNJjTclTmvdNaA2uAgwXhrwwX7Cgs6kxtuWnIL7tcXQrMFUTJua9bwTOjRPZGrTkZ3u2Gy25FhxvFvs13@aGfkNda8eb1auCKoavL0Pa9VUyl3hY9A@Xoam/pZM5ZKXxowd3Te9wLZpORc4o16lcUAvmktnw/Q3KYMrt/PLrxh4@q/Gf/GY9AHFqKPcvrSWXGitXb/cKZ1hlIpcpTmdbxkZtbDQp1zxkd3fNwcGT/U@r7C3t0SuNDc485qjUBd7GpJZoJD@6hSNzaqEA/BWq@kChbdRuX7n2TzFJoJFZmeV0brt6zH0oU9iPoGIqSBOsq5TbNzgE10yzI5a52WU0vlX0k8WCmkSVMRW7tYydUWUYaI8ZK6b5dNKq4gjNKtMdA16CywBijpns9k96cvzs/gbq8am1n@kYZYpgvySiAlWE@LdxYytDXBN@9U7uP0f) It is also a full featured tester. I'd like to explain how to use it if I know Javascript, but unfortunately I don't. Feel free to edit this post if you can add an explanation.

Comment: There were a lot of comments here that were getting cluttered but to avoid deleting any important context, I've [moved them to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134649/discussion-on-question-by-xiver77-implement-constant-latency-branchless-multipli).

Answer (score 2):

## <s>87</s> <s>82</s> 80, destroying `c`

```
shl c
mskc a
and a, d

shl a
rcl c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
setc b

shl a
rcl c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
rcl b

shl a
rcl c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
rcl b

shl a
rcl c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
rcl b

shl a
rcl c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
rcl b

shl a
rcl c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
rcl b

shl a
rcl c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
rcl b

add b, c
```

82 preserving `c` is trivial from 80 destroying it

Didn't notice that mul from most significant is faster

## 104

```
1 reg a # output low
1 reg b # output high
1 reg c # input 
1 reg d # input
1 reg e # cur
1 reg f # back
0 # bit 0
1 ror d
1 msk a, C # mskc a by OP
2 and a, c
1 mov b, a
0 # bit 1
1 rol c
1 ror d
1 msk e, C
2 and e, c
1 mov f, e
2 and e, 254
2 add a, e
3 adc b, f
1 rol c
1 ror d
1 msk e, C
2 and e, c
1 mov f, e
2 and e, 252
2 add a, e
3 adc b, f
1 rol c
1 ror d
1 msk e, C
2 and e, c
1 mov f, e
2 and e, 248
2 add a, e
3 adc b, f
1 rol c
1 ror d
1 msk e, C
2 and e, c
1 mov f, e
2 and e, 240
2 add a, e
3 adc b, f
1 rol c
1 ror d
1 msk e, C
2 and e, c
1 mov f, e
2 and e, 224
2 add a, e
3 adc b, f
1 rol c
1 ror d
1 msk e, C
2 and e, c
1 mov f, e
2 and e, 192
2 add a, e
3 adc b, f
1 rol c
1 ror d
1 msk e, C
2 and e, c
1 mov f, e
2 and e, 128
2 add a, e
3 adc b, f
0 # fix b
2 sub b, a
```

Writing `set a, C` feel better and align friendly than `setc a`

Comment: [Test code](https://pastebin.com/rz60cYY4)

Comment: `and e, C` is a non-existing operation, did you mean `and e, c`? It seems so looking at your test code.

Comment: Nice, your code runs fine when translated to x64 assembly ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/YshrTYbTh)).

Comment: [tio link at end of fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cn2uehkm/)

Comment: I've just edited to state clearly that you don't have to preserve the input.

Answer (score 2):

## Score: <s>94</s> 92

Reduced score by 1 thanks to @xiver77.

```
rol c
mskc a
and a, d
shl a
setc b
rol c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
adc b, 0
shl a
rcl b
rol c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
adc b, 0
shl a
rcl b
rol c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
adc b, 0
shl a
rcl b
rol c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
adc b, 0
shl a
rcl b
rol c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
adc b, 0
shl a
rcl b
rol c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
adc b, 0
shl a
rcl b
rol c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
adc b, 0
```

Explanation:

```
rol c
mskc a
and a, d
```

Multiply the MSB of `c` by `d`.

```
shl a
rcl b
rol c
mskc e
and e, d
add a, e
adc b, 0
```

For each of the remaining seven bits, double `ba` and add `d` multiplied by the bit (`setc b` is used instead of `rcl b` for the first bit since it scores 1 fewer).

Comment: Are you using `f` as a zero register? Then I think it's better to write `adc b, 0` to save register usage.

Comment: @xiver77 Although as @l4m2 points out it's actually cheaper to keep `f`...